# Dynamically calculate top property with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, properties

I am trying to write a script, so elements on a page scroll slower/faster than their parent div. I have wrote this:

```
$('#two').css({'top' : 600-($(this).scrollTop() / 1.2)+"px"});
```

My element is already 600px from the top and if I start scrolling the page from top-everything is fine, since it has these 600px to calculate from, but if I refresh the page right on the element, it jumps top, and console logs that top is calculated from 0, but not from 600px, where it is placed.

I tried to rewrite using `offsetHeight` and other methods(e.g.`offset().top`), but nothing seems to work.

Could you, please, give me a hint on how to make it recalculate dynamically, so when refreshing the page from the middle it won't jump up?

Answer (score 0):

Use position fixed property Even when you scroll the element's position remains fixed.

```
<style>
   #two {
       position: fixed;
       top: 600px;
   }
</style>
```